# USB 3 stick in USB 2 port

Tags: usb, speed, usb-3, usb-2

If I plug a USB 3 stick (with 20/60MBps write/read speed) into a USB 2 port is it possible to get this speed (because USB 2 should be able to get 480Mbps = 60MBps)?

I would assume that this speed could be handled if nothing else interferes (like other USB devices on the same controller or something like that).

Comment: I would think that getting 60MBps as theoretically possible is rather a little overoptimistic expectation. I cannot tell the general thing, but my personal exerience is that 20MBps was the best I could get with USB2.0 connections (though I expect the hardware connected, drives etc to have been quicker, so USB 2.0 being the bottle-neck)

Comment: A USB 3.0 stick would be limited to USB 2.0 speeds if placed in a USB 2.0 port.  This is because the USB 3.0 stick would be seen as a USB 2.0 device to the operating system.

Comment: Check out the last picture in http://superuser.com/questions/527816/usb-2-0-3-0-how-do-you-tell-the-difference   It shows you an USB 3 plug which has the same pins as USB2 and will work **just like USB2** (including speeds) when connected to an USB2 port.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Like humanityANDpeace's comment states, 20 MBps is around the best you will get from USB 2.0 in practice. This is also what I have experienced using various hardware. It's simply the limitation of the interface; plugging in a USB 3.0 stick will not suddenly upgrade your interface.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0_.28High_Speed.29) states the following:

> Released in April 2000. Added higher maximum signaling rate of 480
>   Mbit/s (effective throughput up to 35 MB/s or 280 Mbit/s)

Personally, I can't recall achieving 35 MBps, but it is not inconceivable with certain configurations.

Comment: I have one external HDD where I do archive 35MB/sec (and two which are significantly less). All three with fast enough drives and on the same desktop.

Comment: I've definitely seen sustained transfers over 30 Mb/s using USB 3 devices in USB 2 rated ports.