# How to get low level information from a USB key?

Tags: linux, usb

I am running Debian/Linux, and I would like to know what low level tools are available to print detailed information about a USB key (eg. USB 1.0 vs USB 2.0…). Neither `dmesg`, nor `lsusb` have proved to be useful so far.

I am interested in the key itself, not the connector as in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/527816/usb-2-0-and-usb-3-0-how-can-you-tell-the-difference). For instance I'd like to compare two USB keys where the plastic is white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to query a device properties, nowadays, is via `udevadm`:

```
# udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb
 P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb
 N: sdb
 S: disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_TTFEAZVTZPCNBF3Q-0:0
 S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
 E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_TTFEAZVTZPCNBF3Q-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-  usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
 E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
 E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb
 E: DEVTYPE=disk
 E: ID_BUS=usb
 E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
 E: ID_MODEL=STORE_N_GO
 E: ID_MODEL_ENC=STORE\x20N\x20GO\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
 E: ID_MODEL_ID=0302
 E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
 E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
 E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
 E: ID_REVISION=1100
 E: ID_SERIAL=Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_TTFEAZVTZPCNBF3Q-0:0
 E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=TTFEAZVTZPCNBF3Q
 E: ID_TYPE=disk
 E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
 E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
 E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
 E: ID_VENDOR=Verbatim
 E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Verbatim
 E: ID_VENDOR_ID=18a5
 E: MAJOR=8
 E: MINOR=16
 E: SUBSYSTEM=block
 E: USEC_INITIALIZED=503624797
```

Different alternatives:

1. If you just want to query `sysfs` for the device path (from `/sys` !!) of device `/dev/sdb`, use:

   ```
   # udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/sdb
     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb
   ```
2. If you want to query the symbolic link pointing to `/dev/sdb`,

   ```
   # udevadm info --query=symlink --name=/dev/sdb
     disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_TTFEAZVTZPCNBF3Q-0:0 disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
   ```
3. If you only want the properties of the disk,

   ```
   udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/sdb
   ```
4. If you want the properties of the device, **and** of its parent devices,

   ```
    udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sdb
   ```

Comment: Thanks ! `sysfs` was too complex to use, since I got confused in between information from the controller itself vs the USB key.

Comment: @malat I agree, that's why `udevadm info` was designed in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Dig into `/sys`. Start with `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` or `/sys/class/block/sdX/` (where `sdX` corresponds to your USB key). Read files.

This is how to get some information on USB port (I have no USB key at the moment to give better example):

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/version
 2.00
```

[More about `/sys`](https://superuser.com/q/794198/432690). There are tools that give information in a fancier way. Still, one may be surprised what can be found in `/sys`.